# How can i use Ajax toolkit tabbed pane in asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

i have been using Ajax toolkit tabbed pane, but i dont know how can i add panels to it, like in c# we can add panels, and in panels we add c# form class to further implement, but in it, as it is ajax based, what would be required, please help with some code, thanks.

Atif

Answer (score 0):

It's really not good practice to use the ajax toolkit since you don't know what code is working behind and you can't prove that to 100%. I'd suggest you take a look at jQuery and start of with simple Tabs like this (the code is taken from [jQuery tabs example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>

<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have seen Jquery tabs, but if there is option in .net, then we should avail that, because jquery has also its own issues some times, for large pages or large data.